# Identify 8-pin SMC "385-1"

Tags: identification

I am looking for the part number of this component. Any idea? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Probably an LM385 from onsemi, seen in [this datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/lm285-d.pdf).

It matches the marking code shown on the right side of page 1 for the SOIC package.

The markings indicate that this is the 1.235 V version (that's what the -1 is for; for the 2.500 V version it'd be a -2). The second line is a date and lot code, but beyond that I can't find information on the encoding used from a brief search.

Comment: LM385 maybe but without logo...hard

Comment: @courantelectro Easy enough to test. The LM385 looks basically like a zener diode between two pins, with everything else unconnected.

Comment: @courantelectro Also, note that several manufacturers make LM385s. I know compatible parts are made at least by Analog Devices, Texas Instruments, and onsemi.